# listview items grouping with order by date in xamarin forms

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, grouping

I have a Image gallery app with list view in xamarin forms.I was grouped the list view by date wise in descending order with the help of https://montemagno.com/enhancing-xamarin-forms-listview-with-grouping/ .Now i want to display days in group header for last one week . if the image added today it has to show today,then yesterday,for 7 days ago file last week,for last months item Last month.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Good to see you got part of it working. However, I'd like to see some more effort in the thing you're trying to achieve. What did you try already? Where did it fail? We have absolutely no code to work with, which makes it kind of impossible to fix this for you. Even more so, it could look like we would be doing your work. I'd love to help out, but I'd like a bit more info than this. In addition you could have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a good question that will yield response.

Comment: Gerald Versluis Thanks for your quick reply.

Comment: My code is like this   -------        var sorted = from AlbumItemModel in selectedItem.AlbumItems
                         orderby AlbumItemModel.ItemDateTime descending
                         group AlbumItemModel by AlbumItemModel.ItemDateTime into GroupItem
                         select new Grouping<DateTime, AlbumItemModel>(GroupItem.Key, GroupItem);
            ItemGrouped = new ObservableCollection<Grouping<DateTime, AlbumItemModel>>(sorted);